# Why is it "masterpiece" and not "a piece of art"?

Tags: word-choice

Why do you say *masterpiece*, and not *piece of art*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, people [do say “a piece of art”](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+piece+of+art%22), but “masterpiece” is usually a very *special* piece (or work) of art. [Quoting Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masterpiece),

> Masterpiece (or chef d'œuvre) in modern usage refers to a creation that has been given much critical praise, especially one that is considered the greatest work of a person's career or to a work of outstanding creativity, skill or workmanship.

Comment: The term comes from the medieval guild system, where to attain mastery, and with it the right to open your own shop, take apprentices, etc., you had to make a master-piece to show your competence in your craft. (Of course this is pretty oversimplified as far as the history goes - guilds were *very* complex, and varied greatly from place to place.)

Comment: Martha, you should put that in as an answer.

Comment: I agree with Reg. Also, I think you'd be more likely to see "work of art" rather than "piece of art".

Comment: I think it's a question of degree.  Even really bad art can be called a "piece of art", but you wouldn't call it a "work of art" unless it was of fine quality, and "masterpiece" would be reserved for the cream of the crop.